# Python program crashing when printing blob names for large blob container

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage

Recently I've been writing a Python program that prints out the names of all the blobs within a blob container. The program seems to work fine for blob containers that have a decent amount of files.

However, one of the blob containers has roughly 1,100,000 items. When I try to print all of the blobs in this container, my Python program crashes. I'm fairly new to working with Azure in Python, and I was wondering if there was any way to print all of the names of the blobs within the container without crashing (e.g. print a certain number of blob names per a given time).

This is the code I am using to print the names of the blobs in a given container:

```
generator = container_client.list_blobs()
for item in generator:
  print("Container: {0}, Blob:
  {1}\n".format(container_client.container_name, item.name))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [List-Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/List-Blobs?redirectedfrom=MSDN) has a limit to list maximum 5000 results. If you want to get more than 5000 results you have to use the **NextMarker** to get the continuous token and the results of all lists of blobs.

#### List the overall blob names

```py
nextMarker = None
blobsArray = []

while True:
generator = container_client.list_blobs('<Your_Container>', nextMarker=nextMarker)
    blobsArray.extend(generator)

# Using next_market to get Contiuous Token and the rest of the blob result
    if not generator.next_marker:
        break
    nextMarker = generator.next_marker
    
for item in blobsArray:
    print("Container: {0}, Blob:{1}\n".format(container_client.container_name, item.name))
```